# gradle autoincrement build and custom outputFile (path+name) only for release

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

#### My goal is to:

- have **build** (`0.0.<this>`) number auto increment on each **release** build,
- have current version in fileName, ex `com.meedamian.testApp-wear-1.0.0-1111.apk`,
- have the actual APK version **in sync** with fileName,
- be able to build **and deploy** release builds with a default `ctrl+R`

#### What's wrong with [my current attempt](https://gist.github.com/chester1000/c1aaa0978eb4c681e202):

- version is bumped on each build (both debug and release), as well as any sync,
- apk version is always one ahead of version in a fileName,
- after successful release builds, Android Studio gets lost and complains either `Local path doesn't exist.` or caches version from each sync and shows: `I/O Error: <path-to-apk-file> (No such file or directory)` with the same version no matter how many builds occur in between syncs.

---

I did check many other topics here, I did not find any that covered my problem.

Comment: The third wrong thing happens, I think, because file names in apk and gradle are different (as you mentioned in second wrong thing). Second one: what about i--, if this happens always? Why not to use git commit sha instead of autoincrement?